# Downloading All Office 365 Mail with Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, email, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I have the following C# Code that retrieves email from Office 365 using Microsoft Graph. The Microsoft Graph NuGet Package is version 5.0.0. I am using .NET 6.0 This code will only return the first 10 messages. I know I need to do a paged query but after referring to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp

The examples shown that include the ".Request()" or ".Select() cause an CS1061 error which indicates that the extension methods don't exist. Likewise if I want to include the attachments with the messages, I used to use the .Expand("attachments").

Am I missing required include?

Thanks
William

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Graph;


namespace ReadOffice365Mail
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var tenantId = "MytenantID";
            var clientId = "MyClientID";

            var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
            {
                TenantId = tenantId,
                ClientId = clientId,
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
            };

            // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.interactivebrowsercredential
            var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

            // Define a new Microsoft Graph service client.            
            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential);

var messagesResponse = graphServiceClient.Me.Messages
                        .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                        {
                            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[]{
                            "From",
                            "Sender",
                            "ToRecipients",
                            "internetMessageHeaders",
                            "InternetMessageId",
                            "Subject",
                            "ReceivedDateTime"
                                 };
                            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 100;
                        }).Result;
            if (messages != null && messages.Value != null)
            {
                foreach (var message in messages.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{message.ReceivedDateTime?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")} from {message.From.EmailAddress.Address}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"{message.Subject}");
                    Console.WriteLine("---");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code successfully returns messages, but it is not using page interation.  I have, based on the answer provided by user2250152 I attempted to implement a paged search using the following code:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReadOffice365MailDotNet
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Tenant ID from Azure
            var tenantId = "MyTenantID";

            // Client ID from Azure
            var clientId = "MyClientID";

            // Set the Options for and Interactive Credential.
            var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
            {
                TenantId = tenantId,
                ClientId = clientId,
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
            };

            // Create the the interactive credential with the Options
            var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

            // Create a Graph Serice Credential using the Interactive Credential
            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential);

            // Set the maximum messages to retrive per call to Microsoft Graph.
            Int32 GetMessageCount = 100;

            // Request the messages for the currently signed in user.
            var messagesResponse = graphServiceClient.Me.Messages
                .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                {
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[]
                    {
                        "From",
                        "Sender",
                        "ToRecipients",
                        "internetMessageHeaders",
                        "InternetMessageId",
                        "Subject",
                        "ReceivedDateTime"
                    };
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = GetMessageCount;
                });

            var messageList = new List<Message>();

            var pageIterator = PageIterator<Message, MessageCollectionResponse>
                                .CreatePageIterator(graphServiceClient, messagesResponse, (message) => 
                                { 
                                    messageList.Add(message); 
                                    return true; 
                                });

            await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
            while(pageIterator.State != PagingState.Complete) 
            {
                await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
            }
}
```

However, this code retuns the following compile time error for the return from the PageInterator. Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' Error CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible.

I would appreciate an insight you may have so that I can implement the page interator.

Thanks

Comment: When using `Microsoft Graph 5.0`, the code should remove `.Request()`. Could you pls take a try?

Comment: Hello, yes, I had not originaly removed the .Request().  I copied the wrong version of my code to this post.  As I stated the code will download the first 10 messages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `PageIterator`. `PageIterator` has property `State` which indicates whether the iteration has started or whether is completed.

Let's say that I have 5 messages in mailbox and I want to retrieve only 3 messages by one call.

In `CreatePageIterator` you can specify callback action. I will add the current message to a list of messages.

`pageIterator.State` is `NotStarted` when I call `pageIterator.IterateAsync()` then first 3 items are returned and the callback function is invoked and `pageIterator.State` is `IntrapageIteration`.

Until `pageIterator.State` is not `Complete` I will call `pageIterator.IterateAsync()` to return data from next page

```
var messagesResponse = await graphServiceClient.Me.Messages.GetAsync(x=>
{
    x.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "createdDateTime" };
    x.QueryParameters.Top = 3;
    // Expand property is missing - looks like a bug in v5
    //x.QueryParameters.Expand = new string [] {"attachments"}
});
var messageList = new List<Message>();
var pageIterator = PageIterator<Message, MessageCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(graphServiceClient, messagesResponse, (message) => 
    { 
        messageList.Add(message); 
        return true; 
    });

await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
while(pageIterator.State != PagingState.Complete) 
{
    await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
}
```

In `GetAsync` you can specify query parameters like filter, select and expand. For some reason there is no `Expand` property on `MessagesRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters`. It seems to me like a bug in v5.

##### Workaround to expand attachments

Here is a workaround to add Expand to request

```
var request = graphServiceClient.Me.Messages.ToGetRequestInformation(x =>
        {
            x.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "createdDateTime" };
            x.QueryParameters.Top = 3;
        });
request.QueryParameters["%24expand"] = new string[] { "attachments" };
var index = request.UrlTemplate.Length;
request.UrlTemplate = request.UrlTemplate.Insert(index - 1, ",%24expand");

var messagesResponse = await new Microsoft.Graph.Me.Messages.MessagesRequestBuilder(request.URI.OriginalString, _client.RequestAdapter).GetAsync();

var messageList = new List<Message>();
var pageIterator = PageIterator<Message, MessageCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(_client.RequestAdapter, messagesResponse, (message) =>
        {
            messageList.Add(message);
            return true;
        });

await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
while (pageIterator.State != PagingState.Complete)
{
    await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this response.   The Querry Paramters addition to GetAsync does as you suggest. However, as you point out there is no Expand Property available.  It is still not obvious how to expand the attachments. 

I shamelessly copied your pageIterator code, but I am receiving the following compile time error for the return from the PageInterator.  

Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>'

Error CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible

Comment: The ExpandProperty("") function can be replaced by adding a QueryParameters.Select to the GetAsync Method.  I have updated my example.  I still have not been successful with the PageIterator example you have provided.

Comment: @WilliamHolmes Your Main method is void and you make synchronous calls. Could you please update your code and the code with PageIterator which fails, so I can try to reproduce it.  For Expand there is a ticket in: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1672

Comment: @WilliamHolmes I updated the answer with a workaround how to add expand to a request

Comment: I provided an update to this post but for some reason it was deleted by the moderator.